# Uncaught TypeError: Todos is null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm going through a Java-Script bootcamp course.

Ive attempted to follow the instructions but for some reason after clearing the dummy array and introducing  localstorage parse and stringify methods, I get an uncaught Type error referencing to the variable in the render function.

Ive compared my code to the instructors but cant seem to find why his code doesn't present the same issue.

Your time and guidance is much appreciated.

```js
let todos = []

const filters = {
  searchText: '',
  hideCompleted: false
}

const todosJSON = localStorage.getItem('todos')

if (todosJSON !== null) {
  todos = JSON.parse(todosJSON)
}

const renderTodos = function(todos, filters) {
  const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function(todo) {
    return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
  })

  filteredTodos = filteredTodos.filter(function(todo) {
    if (filters.hideCompleted) {
      return !todo.completed
    } else {
      return true
    }
  })

  const incompleteTodos = filteredTodos.filter(function(todo) {
    return !todo.completed
  })

  document.querySelector("#todoList").innerHTML = ''

  const summary = document.createElement('h2')
  summary.textContent = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`
  document.querySelector("#todoList").appendChild(summary)

  filteredTodos.forEach(function(todo) {
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.textContent = todo.text
    document.querySelector("#todoList").appendChild(p)
  })


}

renderTodos(todos, filters)

document.querySelector("#todo-searcher").addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  filters.searchText = e.target.value
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
})

document.querySelector("#textOfTodo").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  todos.push({
    text: e.target.elements.todoText.value,
    completed: false
  })
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todosJSON))
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
  e.target.elements.todoText.value = ''
})

document.querySelector("#hide-completed-todos").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  filters.hideCompleted = e.target.checked
  renderTodos(todos, filters)
})
```

```html
<h1>Todos</h1>
<input id="todo-searcher" type="text" placeholder="Search for a Todo">
<label>Hide Completed
                    <input id="hide-completed-todos" type="checkbox">
                    </label>
<div id="todoList"></div>
<form id="textOfTodo">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Todo Description" name="todoText">
  <button>Add Todo</button>
</form>

<script src="todo-app.js"></script>
```

Instructors version:

```
const renderTodos = function (todos, filters) {
    const filteredTodos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
        const searchTextMatch = todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
        const hideCompletedMatch = !filters.hideCompleted || !todo.completed

        return searchTextMatch && hideCompletedMatch
    })

    const incompleteTodos = filteredTodos.filter(function (todo) {
        return !todo.completed
    })

    document.querySelector('#todos').innerHTML = ''

    const summary = document.createElement('h2')
    summary.textContent = `You have ${incompleteTodos.length} todos left`
    document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(summary)

    filteredTodos.forEach(function (todo) {
        const p = document.createElement('p')
        p.textContent = todo.text
        document.querySelector('#todos').appendChild(p)
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`. You should use `let filteredTodos` instead of `const filteredTodos`, it's not a constant. Also please provide the relevant HTML (you can edit your question) because other errors are popping as the script can't find `#todo-searcher` or `#todoList`, so your actual problem is hard to reproduce currently.

Comment: edited, I also changed it to let filteredtodos but that didnt seem to solve it.
I have also added the instructor's version of the render block.

Comment: Please add that HTML not as a simple code snippet but instead to your existing stack snippet (Click "edit the above snippet" after clicking "Edit" [the question] to paste the html to it)

Comment: I have integrated your HTML to the snippet I had made. After commenting out the LocalStorage part (it doesn't work because snippets are sandboxed, that's normal), I'm not getting any error. How are you getting yours?

Comment: Ah, got it. It's on reload. So it has to do with the LocalStorage part. I'm on it

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple typo. You are saving this to LocalStorage :

```
 localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todosJSON))
```

but `todosJSON` is null at start, and this gets saved to LS, so it will always be null. You want to save

```
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
```